VB.Net: Value of type 'List(Of Reference)' cannot be converted to 'List(Of Reference)'
I don't understand why this is an error, to me it should just work. Can someone help me to understand why this is an issue so I can rectify the problem.
The "searchRef.Execute" part is the bit throwing the error
Thanks
Public Function [Get](ByVal search As String) As JsonResult(Of String)
    Dim searchRef As New SearchReference(search)
    Dim references As List(Of Reference) = searchRef.Execute()
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    For Each ref As Reference In references
        row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
            {"rID", ref.ReferenceID},
            {"rText", ref.Reference},
            {"rURL", ref.ReferenceURL}
        }
        rows.Add(row)
    Next

    Return Json(jss.Serialize(rows))
End Function

Public Class SearchReference
    Private sql As String
    Private dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Private ReadOnly sqlParams As List(Of SqlParameter) = New List(Of SqlParameter)()

    Public Property Search As String

    Public Sub New(_search As String)
        Search = _search
    End Sub

    Public Function Execute() As List(Of Reference)
        Dim References As New List(Of Reference)

        sqlParams.Clear()
        sqlParams.Add(New SqlParameter("@Search", Search))
        sql = "SQL query will go here"
        dt = SQLDB.fetchMultipleValues(sql, userDB, sqlParams)

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            References.Add(New Reference(dr.Item("ReferenceID"), dr.Item("Reference"), dr.Item("ReferenceURL")))
        Next

        Return References
    End Function

End Class


The most obvious issue would be if those two pieces of code are referencing different types that both happen to be named Reference. You need to work to create a [mcve] so that we can actually see the code in our own tools

Thanks for that, soon as I forced them to the namespace, they worked. Scary things is I can't find another class called Reference. Joys!

You can right-click on a type name in code and be taken to the place it's defined. That will even work in referenced libraries as VS will decompile the code.
